# How can I deploy cdk python to multiple environment to self.node.try_get_context('env') and some logic to specify where the stack gets deployed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have created the following vpc class using python aws cdk, I need help understanding how to dynamicaly set the env  variable through self.node.try_get_context('env') to represent the environment where the stack will be deployed, for example prod,dev,stg etc. since I'm reusing it in my logic to formulate naming convention for the stack.

I have assigned env variables in the cdk.json as
"env_stg": "stg",
"env_prd": "prd",

I can call them individually but lack understanding calling them dynamically to affect my environments on the fly.

I really appreciate any help

```py
class VPC(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        env = self.node.try_get_context('env')

        self.vpc =ec2.Vpc(self, "Stg",
            cidr = '10.0.0.0/16',
            max_azs = 2,
            enable_dns_support = True,
            enable_dns_hostnames = True,
                subnet_configuration = [
                    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                        name = 'Public',
                        subnet_type = ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                        cidr_mask = 24
                    ),
                    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                        name = 'Isolated',
                        subnet_type = ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
                        cidr_mask = 24                      
                    )
                ]       
        )

        # Store all private subnets in Parameter store 

        private_subnets = [subnet.subnet_id for subnet in self.vpc.private_subnets]

        # public_subnets = [subnet.subnet_id for subnet in self.vpc.public_subnets]
        count = 1 
        for subnets in private_subnets:
            ssm.StringParameter(self, 'private-subnet-'+str(count),
            string_value = subnets,
            parameter_name = '/'+env+'/pivate-subnet-'+str(count)
            )
            count += 1
```

Comment: what questions do you have about it ?

Comment: so i have 2 different AWS accounts,
1) prd 
2) stg
i have configured both accounts via aws cli on my machine
in this case i am deploying the same stack in 2 accounts
i am using the env variable which uses the context variable for my naming convention so ...
currently  [cdk drploy -c env='prd' --profile prod  and cdk deploy -c env='dev' --profile dev ] works,  
But i'm trying to achieve this dynamically somehow  because i am using env in my string formatting for ssm parameter.
is there a way to pass in  context variable on  the application entry point ? or is it to be done with logic ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need new env vars or context.  [Stacks can introspect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html#stack_api) their [Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html) (= account + region) at synth-time. Use Python's language features to derive account-specific labels from the Stack's account.

```py
# vpc_stack.py

env_label = "stg"

if self.account == "123456789012":
  env_label = "prod"
```

Even better, lift the label logic up to the app level, using the CDK-provided `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` environment variable. Its value is set at synth-time based on the cli `--profile` flag value.  Pass the labels down to the stacks in the stack props (kwargs).  This way, configuration is more central, visible and resusable across stacks.

```py
# app.py

account = os.environ["CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT"]

env_label = "stg"

if account == "123456789012":
  env_label = "prod"
```

You can get even fancier than this, but these are some basic patterns.